# carousel image is blurred while responsive

Tags: html, css, carousel, responsive, bootstrap-5

[image]

Carousel images are being blurred when it's tried responsive.. alignment is correct but image is getting blurred when screen resolution is decreased. I'm using Bootstrap.

Web site - first carousel: https://www.asus.com/in/

(WHEN I TRIED USING  IMAGE FLUID IT'S IMAGE BECOMES SMALLER )

CODE :

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/corasel-img1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/corasel-img2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/corasel-img3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
```

CSS :

```
.carousel-item{
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 300px;
}
.w-100{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

MY IMAGE IS BLURRED WHEN IT'S BEEN RESPONSIVE

[image]

Comment: I doesn't really look blurred to me, it looks 'squished' - it's lost its aspect ratio. What do you want it to look like when the aspect ratio of the viewport differs from the aspect ratio of the image? You may want either contain or cover as the object-fit (the first will show all the image, but it wont cover the viewport, and the second will cover the viewport, cutting off either the sides or the top/bottom to fit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add **object fit** rule to your image element(s).

Code for you:

```css
.carousel-item img{
   object-fit: cover;
}
```